# Linux disk moved on a different server won't boot

Tags: linux, boot

I have a server HP Proliant DL120 G6, with an installed and working Ubuntu 14.04. The partitioning is reported below.

Now, if I move the disks on a very similar HP Proliant DL120 G5, in the same order, they don't even boot: no error, nothing, as if the disks are empty. I tried switching them, no luck.

This baffles me. How is that possible?

## Details

The disks can be seen by the new server, and I don't get a "boot error" from BIOS. I just keep seeing the cursor blinking at the top left of the screen.

None of the servers has additional RAID controllers.

The destination server is actually booting and working with its own disks: my original plan was to replace the existing disks and to save time I installed the system on a different system.

Booting from a LiveCD, I can confirm everything is fine on the disks: partitions are there, the RAID array are ok.

## Partitioning

```
/dev/sda1 + /dev/sdb1 = /dev/md0 = /boot
/dev/sda2 = swap
/dev/sdb2 = swap
/dev/sda3 + /dev/sdb3 = /dev/md1 = /
```

## Note

I know how to fix the problem with a boot repair disk, or I can even reinstall for that matter. I am just very interested to know what is the possible cause for this issue.

Comment: If the disks are empty, you'd get a notice about boot medium failure. Without knowing more, this baffles me too. Linux systems are usually easily portable to another machine, with or without MD RAID. If you do boot into a rescue system, can you find the disks?

Comment: "*they don't even boot: no error, nothing*": frankly, I don't believe you.  The BIOS would complain if no boot sector could be found.  If the BIOS is handing over to the primary HDD, but the sector points off into space and things are hanging there, that isn't failure: that's partial success.  You need to tell us in much more detail **what** is happening before we can help you understand **why**.

Comment: I have updated my question with some details.

Comment: Where, exactly, sda and sdb were connected on the SOURCE G5? I mean, does it (the G5) have a RAID controller? If yes, which is, exactly (a "real" one, or a "fake" one?). If connected to common SATA/SAS/SCSI bus, which is the involved controller? As for the G6, please report same information: does it have a raid controller? or a normal controller? Also, please, report details about "boot-order" of both  systems (it's even possible that the G6 is configured with **disabled** HD boot!)

Comment: Also, please confirm there's a typo in your question as... it's not possible that `/dev/md0` is the block device holding mount-points for **BOTH** `/boot` and `/`

Comment: This sounds a lot like the behavior when you have a mismatch between the drive modes (IDE, AHCI, RAID, etc.) in the BIOS.  I'd check and make sure the mode is the same on both the G6 and G5.

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli thanks for lots of input, I have updated and fixed my question. Notes: 1) the destination server is actually booting and running fine with its own disks installed locally; the issue is only when I replace them with two new disks containing a system prepared on another server 2) normal SATA controllers on both servers, and please note that the disks can be mount correctly from a LiveCD. I don't get boot errors from BIOS.

Comment: @BrandonXavier thank you, I will check. But again, the disks can be seen an mounted fine from a LiveCD.

Comment: I would bet for a GRUB2 problem: the boot, as seen from the hardware perspective, is completed and control is given to boot-loader (GRUB2, I guess). For some reason, the bootloader is not able to start. If you press and hold down Shift key since the the Bios screen is presented to you, what happens right after? Still nothing / the blank-screen?

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli unfortunately I cannot do tests since the server it's a customer site. I am going to use the Ubuntu Boot Repair Disk and in the worst case to reinstall from scratch (it's a very simple system).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. In some way I am relieved that I did not overlook some simple setting / process, and that it's actually an unexpected behaviour.